# Mail spelling checker will not stop

Tags: spellcheck

This is driving me crazy.

I have gone into Preferences and set spellchecking -> NEVER

But it will not stop!

:
  :

[image]

This gets my goat. I rarely if ever make spelling errors, and it is constantly getting in my way.

Is there some way to get rid of it once and for all?

EDIT: I use Mavericks' native speech recognition; maybe there're some conflict?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They blue lines are alternate speech recognition hints. Spelling is in red, not dark blue.

I don't know of a way to disable the blue lines directly other than enunciating in a way that the engine has less uncertainty about what you are dictating.